# Unable to click link

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click="selectPage(totalPages)" class="ng-binding">Last</a>
```

I have the following code on VBA:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//span[text()='Next']").Click
```

which says element not found. 
to click on 
link. [source page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsmax.png)

Comment: The text is "Last", not "next".

Comment: try driver.findElement(by.linkText("Last")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this :**
There are some trailing spaces in anchor tag which you have shown in attached image, so use **normalize-space()** method instead of **text()**, it will trim the spaces.

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[normalize-space()='Next']").Click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tag with text as **Last** is an *Angular* element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[@class='ng-binding' and contains(.,'Last')]"))).Click
```

Answer (score 0):

I think by **Next**, you mean the the link before the **Last** which you highlighted in the Source page.

To Click on link "Last" use below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Last")).click();
```

If the above doesn't help then add explicit wait(may be 10 seconds) and check, you can use below code for that :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Last")));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Last")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve using following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ng-click='selectPage(totalPages)']")).click();
```